# Align an image at the right of a text in LyX

Tags: graphics, positioning, lyx, titles

I am LyX user and I would like to align an image at the right side of my title but I don't know how..:/

I am using as module "report". I've attached a screenshot in order to illustrate where I want to put the image:

[image]

How can I put my image over there?

Comment: How are you producing the title? Can you please add to your question a minimal example of the code used to write the title?

Comment: I only wrote the text on Lyx .. I didnt use any code :/ Just wrote the text you can see on the screenshot above and i want to put a figure on the right side :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is step-by-step how to do the same as Gonzalo's approach, but using only LyX menus etc.:

1. Create a new box, by clicking  [image] on
   the toolbar, or selecting Insert ⇒ Box ⇒ Frameless.
2. Right click the name of the box (where it says `Box (Minipage)`, and choose Settings. Set the width to 55. Write your text in this box.
3. Put the marker outside the box, and make another box. This time set the width to 45, and set the vertical alignment for the `Content` to `Bottom`.
4. Add your image in this box, by clicking [image] or selecting Insert ⇒ Graphics.
5. Remove the indentation from the paragraph, by right clicking in the empty area to left of the first box, choosing Paragraph settings, and unchecking the box `Indent paragraph`.

Change the vertical alignment and widths to suit you.

(You'll get the same I'd think by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (or Insert ⇒ TeX code) and pasting in the document part of Gonzalo's code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, or Edit -> Paste special -> Plain text. If you don't use paste special linebreaks in the code will be ignored, which will make everything after the `%` be ignored because it's commented out.)

Comment: Nice manual with the little pictures! You can use `<kbd>` for keystrokes, as I did in my edit. (The Unicode arrows are just for fun ..)

Answer (score 6):

The following example shows a possible solution, but I have no idea how to implement it in LyX. You can use two side by side `minipage`s; the first one will contain the text, and the second one will contain the image. A little example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.55\textwidth}
  \bfseries
  \Huge Some Text \\
  Some Text \\
  \Large Some more text \\
  Some more text \\
  \normalsize And even more text \\
  And even more text
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{name}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Feel free to adjust the width of the `minipage`s and the image height according to your needs. I used the `demo` option for the `graphicx` package to make my example compilable for everyone; do *not* use that option in your actual code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I did it this in Lyx (its an option called boxes ) but i have now another issue : The text is lower than the image . Just look the screenshot above :

http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/1452/screenshot2iu.png

Any ideas ? :)

Comment: @ALdaperan: the `minipage` environment admits an optional argument controlling its vertical alignment with respect to the surrounding elements, so you could use, for example `\begin{minipage}[b]{.55\textwidth}...\end{minipage}` and `\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}...\end{minipage}`. Perhaps there's a similar feature for boxes in LyX. If not, then let me know and I'll suggest you another approach.

Comment: There is, one can change the vertical alignment of box (and content) in the settings of the box.