# Place an image inlined with a paragraph

Tags: lyx

I want to place an image inlined with a paragraph, as seen in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29474/align-an-image-at-the-right-of-a-text-in-lyx)

I followed the steps in the first answer, and it works well, but the text is sligthly higher than the the picture, as seen here:
[image]

How can I make the text start exactly where the image starts? I know I can control the vertical alignment of the boxes, but I tried a lot of options and didn't got near to what I've wanted.
I'm trying to solve it using lyx tools, without needing me to write actual latex code.

Comment: I have no idea about lyx, but if you can control the options of the image, you could move it up a bit with the trim option, e.g. `\includegraphics[trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.7ex]{....}` (adjust the 0.7ex if needed).

Comment: You could use the paracol environment to place image and text in two columns.

Comment: @Photon I'm trying to solve it using lyx tools, without needing me to write actual latex code (if it's possible)

Comment: @Suspicious_1 If you go to the graphics settings, you can change the trim value by going to "LaTeX and LyX options" and then entering `trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 0.7ex` in the "LaTeX options" box.